# How to close sqlalchemy connection in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

This is a sample code I'd like to run:

```
for i in range(1,2000):
    db = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/test_database')
    conn = db.connect()
    #some simple data operations
    conn.close()
    db.dispose()
```

Is there a way of running this without getting "Too many connections" errors from MySQL?
I already know I can handle the connection otherwise or have a connection pool. I'd just like to understand how to properly close a connection from sqlalchemy.

Comment: IMO: you covered the two choices: pooling or outside the loop.

Comment: Looks like your example already. no "Too many connections" here (since the connection is opened/closed inside the loop)

Comment: @martincho even I cant generate the error "Too many connections" from your code :(.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Here's how to write that code correctly:

```
db = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/test_database')
for i in range(1,2000):
    conn = db.connect()
    #some simple data operations
    conn.close()
db.dispose()
```

That is, the `Engine` is a *factory* for connections as well as a *pool* of connections, not the connection itself.   When you say `conn.close()`, the connection is *returned to the connection pool within the Engine*, not actually closed.

If you do want the connection to be actually closed, that is, not pooled, disable pooling via `NullPool`:

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
db = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/test_database', poolclass=NullPool)
```

With the above `Engine` configuration, each call to `conn.close()` will close the underlying DBAPI connection.

If OTOH you actually want to connect to *different* databases on each call, that is, your hardcoded `"localhost/test_database"` is just an example and you actually have lots of different databases, then the approach using `dispose()` is fine; it will close out every connection that is not checked out from the pool.

In all of the above cases, the important thing is that the `Connection` object is closed via `close()`.   If you're using any kind of "connectionless" execution, that is `engine.execute()` or `statement.execute()`, the `ResultProxy` object returned from that execute call should be fully read, or otherwise explicitly closed via `close()`.   A `Connection` or `ResultProxy` that's still open will prohibit the `NullPool` or `dispose()` approaches from closing every last connection.

Comment: `dispose()`!! I needed it to make a session close, as `session.close()` did not suffice. I recommend adding this into the SQLAlchemy documentation, based on my experience it is not clear how to properly close a session.

Comment: you call close(), as documented.  dispose() is not needed and in fact calling dispose() explicitly is virtually never needed for normal SQLAlchemy usage.   Feel free to email the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy) with information about your specific issue, perhaps you executed some special directives like "SET" on your Session which are not cleared out when using pooling (there's a different way to handle that).

Comment: I just posted the info in a new question: [How can I properly close a SQLAlchemy session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738944/how-can-i-properly-close-a-sqlalchemy-session) If it is OK for you to answer here. Otherwise I will contact through the mailing list. Thank you very much!

Comment: @zzzeek a little late to the party, but just wanted to thank you for your incredible work. I've become a patron! (anyone else reading this should, too: https://www.patreon.com/join/zzzeek)

Answer (score 10):

Tried to figure out a solution to disconnect from database for an unrelated problem (must disconnect before forking).

You need to [invalidate](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection.invalidate) the connection from the connection Pool too.

In your example:

```
for i in range(1,2000):
    db = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/test_database')
    conn = db.connect()
    # some simple data operations
    # session.close() if needed
    conn.invalidate()
    db.dispose()
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this one

```
engine = create_engine('...')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS...")
engine.dispose()
```

Comment: with engine.connect() as conn: <- shouldn't after this automatically close my connection?

Answer (score -1):

In my case these always works and I am able to close!
So using invalidate() before close() makes the trick. Otherwise close() sucks.

```
conn = engine.raw_connection()  
conn.get_warnings  = True
curSql = xx_tmpsql
myresults = cur.execute(curSql, multi=True)
print("Warnings: #####")
print(cur.fetchwarnings())
for curresult in myresults:
    print(curresult)
    if curresult.with_rows:
        print(curresult.column_names)
        print(curresult.fetchall())
    else:
        print("no rows returned")
cur.close()
conn.invalidate()
conn.close()     
engine.dispose()
```

Comment: when do you instance cur ?