# How to close a SQLAlchemy session?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

Following what we commented in [How to close sqlalchemy connection in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645250/how-to-close-sqlalchemy-connection-in-mysql/8705750?noredirect=1#comment32872652_8705750), I am checking the connections that SQLAlchemy creates into my database and I cannot manage to close them without exiting from Python.

If I run this code in a python console, it keeps the session opened until I exit from python:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import OneTable, get_engine

engine = get_engine(database="mydb")
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

results = session.query(OneTable.company_name).all()

# some work with the data #

session.close()
```

and the only workaround I found to close it is to call `engine.dispose()` at the end.

As per the comments in the link I gave above, my question are now:

- Why is `engine.dispose()` necessary to close sessions?
- Doesn't `session.close()` suffice?

Comment: Working with `sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool` doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: I hope this two links help you http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/glossary.html?highlight=release and http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/pooling.html?highlight=pooling#switching-pool-implementations

Answer (score 130, accepted):

There's a central confusion here over the word "session".   I'm not sure here, but it appears like you may be confusing the [SQLAlchemy Session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html) with a [MySQL @@session](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html), which refers to the scope of when you first make a connection to MySQL and when you disconnect.

These two concepts are **not the same**.  A SQLAlchemy Session generally represents the scope of **one or more transactions**, upon a particular database connection.

Therefore, the answer to your question as literally asked, is to call `session.close()`, that is, "how to properly close a SQLAlchemy session".

However, the rest of your question indicates you'd like some functionality whereby when a particular `Session` is closed, you'd like the actual DBAPI connection to be closed as well.

What this basically means is that you wish to disable [connection pooling](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html).  Which as other answers mention, easy enough, [use NullPool](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#switching-pool-implementations).

Comment: This completely made it. By you pointing it I noticed I was mixing the SQLAlchemy and MySQL sessions. Now with `get_engine(database="mydb", poolclass=NullPool)` I get it closed once I `session.close()`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess I am having an issue due to sessions not closed properly. My api is giving me random number of rows. e.g. I have 10 rows in my table (mysql). And when I hit my api I get 10, 0, 9, etc. results. P.S. I use sqlalchemy (not flask sqlalchemy). Please guide me.

Answer (score 117):

`session.close()` will give the connection back to the connection pool of Engine and doesn't close the connection.

`engine.dispose()` will close all connections of the connection pool.

Engine will not use connection pool if you set `poolclass=NullPool`. So the connection (SQLAlchemy session) will close directly after `session.close()`.

Comment: Will `.dispose` wait for all pending commits?

Comment: @matanster no, as per the docs: "Connections that are checked out are not discarded when the engine is disposed or garbage collected". So any unclosed sessions will be effectively ignored by `engine.dispose()`

Answer (score -4):

In [LogicBank](https://github.com/valhuber/logicbank), I had a series of unittest tests.  Each test copied a sqlite database prior to running, like this:

```
copyfile(src=nw_source, dst=nw_loc)
```

Each test ran individually, but failed in `discover` mode.  It became apparent that somehow the database copy was not happening.

It appeared that perhaps unittest were not run serially.  Not so - unittests do, in fact, run serially.  So that was ***not*** the problem (logging that, to perhaps save somebody some time).

After a remarkable amount of thrashing, it appears that this was because the database was not ***completely*** closed from the prior test.  *Somehow* that interfered with the copy, above.  Mine is not to wonder why...

Thanks to the posts above, I resolved it like this:

```
def tearDown(file: str, started_at: str, engine: sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine, session: sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session):
"""
close session & engine, banner

:param file: caller, usually __file__
:param started_at: eg, str(datetime.now())
:param engine: eg, nw.logic import session, engine
:param session: from nw.logic import session, engine
:return:
"""

session.close()
engine.dispose(). # NOTE: close required before dispose!

print("\n")
print("**********************")
print("** Test complete, SQLAlchemy session/engine closed for: " + file)
print("** Started: " + started_at + " Ended: " + str(datetime.now()))
print("**********************")
```